# comparing performance of python factorial (math vs. scipy)

Tags: python, factorial

Why is `math.factorial` so much faster than `scipy.special.factorial`?

```
import timeit

t = timeit.timeit("from math import factorial; factorial(20)"); print(t)
0.6399730000412092

t = timeit.timeit("from scipy.special import factorial; factorial(20)"); print(t)
5.339432950946502

t = timeit.timeit("from scipy.special import factorial; factorial(20, exact=True)"); print(t)
1.7984685270348564
```

I am on Python 3.7 (scipy version is 1.1.0)

Answer (score 5):

This is a common mistake, similar to expecting things like `np.exp()` to work faster than from the `math` module. This is not the purpose of such functions. The scientific stack (`NumPy`, `Pandas`, `SciPy` and others) is concerned with vectorized approaches across arrays, not single values.

```
from math import factorial

factorial([20, 20, 20])
```

This will give `TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)`

But:

```
from scipy.special import factorial

factorial([20, 20, 20])
```

Will compute the factorial for the whole list, giving:

```
array([2.43290201e+18, 2.43290201e+18, 2.43290201e+18])
```

If you dropped your `math.factorial` calculation into a `for` loop to cover multiple items in the list, it will very quickly fall behind on timings vs. the vectorized approach (which would be even faster if you supplied a NumPy array rather than a list in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

Beside the already mentioned facts about scipy targetting vectorized inputs - you use a very small test case here - if you widen it, it wont be as clear:

```
import timeit

for z in range(20,100000,10000):
    t1 = timeit.timeit(f"from math import factorial; factorial({z})",number=10)
    t2 = timeit.timeit(f"from scipy.special import factorial; factorial({z})",number=10)
    t3 = timeit.timeit(f"from scipy.special import factorial; factorial({z}, exact=True)",number=10)
    print(f"{z}  : {t1:<20}  {t2:<20}  {t3:<20}")
```

Output:

```
# facNr    factorial          scipy.special.factorial(*)   exact = True
   20  : 0.0003352240000822    0.18152283800009172     6.924199988134205e-05
10020  : 0.0368837539999731    0.00016821899953356478  0.03690350099986972 
20020  : 0.1258954189997894    0.00016980899999907706  0.12552139000035822 
30020  : 0.2532270950005113    0.00017434100027458044  0.2531732979996377  
40020  : 0.4068329990004713    0.00017545999980939087  0.406938215000082   
50020  : 0.6163399690003644    0.0001782059998731711   0.616294079999534   
60020  : 0.8626650409996728    0.00017887300055008382  0.8635997929995938  
70020  : 1.1321934719999263    0.00017422100063413382  1.130675204999534   
80020  : 1.369009857000492     0.00017408599978807615  1.369635687000482   
90020  : 1.7379734959995403    0.00017380499957653228  1.7343564000002516
```

By using a wider range of inputs you see that it is not *always* much faster.

If doing timings, always consider edgecases of few and lots of data together with "normal amount"

---

(*) returns `inf` for `z`>170 - so not calculating it in earnest and timings are skewed

Answer (score 0):

When `exact=True` the scipy function is really just acting as a wrapper around `math.factorial` (see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.0/scipy/special/…) so I guess the extra time is just the overhead of the argument checking logic and extra function call.

When `exact=False` or unspecified you're using an approximation, which will be slower than the exact calculation for small values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

`math.factorial` is a python builtin function, it does not get compiled to python byte code, and is actually executing `c` code.

You can see similar behavior with other functions, such as `numpy` `cos` / `sin` etc...

Comment: This makes no sense. The OP is observing that `math.factorial` works _faster_ than the SciPy equivalent.

Comment: That is exactly what  should happen, while `SciPy` equivalents  compile to byte code and execute it slower, `math.factorial` just calls `c` function, which is faster.

Comment: No, SciPy will drop the calculation down into compiled C code. The issue is that there's some overhead in doing it. The function was never meant to be called on scalars

Comment: I am not sure what are you arguing about, we are saying the same thing. `SciPy` call has overhead, it compiles into `python` byte code and executes. (and has more functionality then `math.factorial`)  `math.factorial` has no overhead at all, not even compiling it into byte code, and execute the `c` code immediately.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a pretty pointless debate on scalars I guess.